# SQL displaying only max value

Tags: sql

I am trying to return a result from sql query where sort by movie title and the highest rating of the movie -  and get rid of the lower rating of the same movie. and theres only 1 select statement allowed.

i tried this;

```
Select distinct m.title, r.stars
from Movie as m inner join Rating as r on m.mid = r.mid
order by m.title
```

but can't figure out how to only choose the higher rating. If anyone has a good resource for the nuances it would help.

Answer (score 4):

use `MAX()` which is an aggregate function that gets the greatest value in a certain field on each group.

```
Select m.title, MAX(r.stars) stars
from Movie as m inner join Rating as r on m.mid = r.mid
GROUP BY m.title
order by m.title
```